# Testing behaviour of classes with deep nested dependencies

Tags: php, testing, tdd, bdd, behat

I am starting using Behat and I was thinking what is the correct way to do something like this:

I am testing system behaviour with Behat (the domain, not web) and i want to test behaviour that uses UserService class. UserService takes UserRepository (Interface) as an argument. Should i create the UserService object in the context or should i take it from some dependency injection container (which i currently don't have since i want to model the domain first)? Or should i maybe create a factory to construct the UserService? Should I mock those dependencies?

The problem here is, that there may be multiple implementations of UserRepository and i want to test the one the system uses (hence taking UserService from DI container). I do not know which implementation i am going to use at the time of writing the feature file/context. Probably just some dummy FilesystemUserRepository just to pass the tests.

If I used the FilesystemUserRepository in contexts, then after i decide to move to DatabaseUserRepository later in development i would have to rewrite all the contexts that use UserService class.

Is there some best practice how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually start with creating everything in my context's constructor, as it's a phase I move back and forward a lot and I don't want to be distracted by having to create service definitions. At this phase code might change a lot, so it would be rather inefficient anyway.

Later on, I create service definitions in the application's container. With the Symfony container it is very easy to [inject those services directly into your context](http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/cookbooks/1.symfony2_integration.html#accessing-application-services-in-contexts). Another advantage is that with Symfony environments you can actually replace some services in test environment. I actually use this a lot, as I prefer to use in-memory repositories in acceptance tests, rather than those based on a database.

On some projects I didn't take the second step, and left all the service initialization in Behat's context class. It worked well too.

Comment: This may be slightly paranoid, but what if i don't want to create coupling to any one DI container this early in development? On the other hand DI containers are the basis of the application nowdays so maybe it's not wrong... I will probably just stick to instantiating everything in context for now.

Comment: It's not really coupled, as this way you're not using the container directly. Symfony2 Behat extension takes care of injecting services. If you ever decided to switch to another container, you'd need a Behat extension that would do injecting for you. Contexts remain the same.

Comment: Nice, this is exactly what i had in mind. Thank you.